# Multiple centroids of complex outline polygons by recursive buffering

Tags: qgis, algorithm, qgis-modeler, canopy-height-model

How can I algorithmically determine multiple centroids for overlapping (dissolved), very irregular regions representing canopy outlines?

This is effectively a forestry issue. The context is that I have canopy outlines I generated with concave hull from a raster. What I want to do now is get centers for each 'bulb' of the complex outline (imagine many overlapping circles).

My thought is to use a negative buffer recursively until I have many small polygons that I can find the centroids of. The challenge is that each time I buffer I will get polygons which should be excluded because they are now independent, small, and should not be buffered again. This needs to be checked on every buffer run.

The raster in the second image is from a separate workflow -- an attempt to extract a point cloud based on coloring the points with NDVI.

I am working in QGIS 3.10, have very limited ability with Python, strong experience in ArcMap and decent experience with ModelBuilder but have never used the modeler in QGIS.

[image: Derived Canopy Outlines from raster boolean]
[image: Concave Hull process image]

Comment: Welcome to the site. Can you show a picture of the canopy outlines raster that you decribe? There is a tool to find the centroid of many polygons (vector -> geometry tools  -> centroids) but this will only work if you have relatively "clean" crowns.

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question

Comment: For each negative buffer itetation first select only polygons larger than a certain area. Or select by compactness/roundness.